# Setting MdiParent property of a form breaks/prevents its Shown event from firing

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mdi

So, i've been searching trough similar topics on stackoverflow and on other internet forums and knowledge bases but so far i had no luck trying to solve this problem i've been struggling for a whole week. Here is the code:

```
    private void matrículasToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form1 form1 = new Form1();
        form1.Show();
        form1.MdiParent = this; // this == the main form of the aplication, wich has IsMdiParent property set to true.
    }
```

If i take out the "form1.MdiParent = this", the shown event of form1 will fire normally, executing all of its handler's content, but if i let it there, shown event of form1 will not fire (i did set breakpoits, none of them triggered).

Curiously, if i use the Load event instead of Shown, everything works fine, but i'm a bit afraid if swapping Shown for Load would break something :(.

Comment: I've found it, updated my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this code

```
 Form1 form1 = new Form1();
 //Subscribe event here
 form1.MdiParent = this;
 form1.Show();
```

This works for me

<strike>I don't know why your code doesn't work, I'll get back once I get the answer.</strike>

Edit: I have got the answer now.

`ISynchronizationInvoke's` members (`Invoke` and `BeginInvoke`) are implemented by `Control` class as follows.

1. Gets context of Thread which created the window.
2. Generate a new window messageId using `RegisterWindowMessage`
3. Encapsulate the delegate we passed as a parameter in `ThreadMethodEntry` add it into control's internal `Queue`
4. Posts the message to thread's queue with messageId returned by `RegisterWindowMessage` using `PostMessage`
5. Handles `WndProc` listens for `messageId` then De-queues the `ThreadMethodEntry` and invokes the delegate.

> What goes wrong here?

Form1 form1 = new Form1();
   form1.Show();
   form1.MdiParent = this;

`Form.Show` somehow results in a call to `OnLoad` method, that is where `OnShown` is called Asynchronously using `BeginInvoke`

```
if (base.IsHandleCreated)
{
    base.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(this.CallShownEvent));//reflected code
}
```

So before the posted `WindowMessage` receives you set `form1.MdiParent = this;` which in turn forces the control to `Destroy` it's handle and `ReCreate` new handle.

`DestroyHandle` method swallows the posted message by getting it using `PeekMessage` function, and then enumerates all elements in `Queue` and sets its state as completed without invoking the delegate but marking it to throw `ObjectDisposedException`.

```
Form1 form1 = new Form1();
form1.Show();
Action del = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine("This will never be called");//our custom delegates too fails to be invoked
};
var res = form1.BeginInvoke(del);
//after some more code
form1.EndInvoke(res);//throws `ObjectDisposedException` which was marked previously
form1.MdiParent = this;
```

throwing `ObjectDisposedException("Control")` is actually misleading isn't it?

Note: You can fix this easily using `Application.DoEvents();` before `form1.MdiParent = this;` since `DoEvents` process all the pending messages immediately.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much!, cant believe i've been struggling with this thing for a week and the solution was that simple :O

Comment: Oh man, a week is a huge time. but cheers you got it now. I'll let you know why it doesn't work once I found it. Am very curious to know why It doesn't work.